# How can I store UIImageViewController in the image

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

I have a project in which I have to store many images in each `UIImageViewController`. If user wants to add new image it will also store in `UIImageViewController`. For doing this according to me, I have to first create `NSMutableArray` and store `UIImageViewController` in it. Please Guide me if I should go with this logic or not.

Comment: Can you re word the question, it's unclear what you want, why would you want to put the controller into an array? Do you mean add the array to your controller?

Comment: Thanks for reply.i just want to store images in the scroller view(Landscpae)

Answer (score 0):

It may well make sense to add an array to your controller (I'm assuming this is what you meant to type).  Personally I'd hold the data in a more abstract class, say ImageRepository that holds the images (proably an array) and the controller references that to get the images (note this class would be the model, the M in MVC).   This is especially useful if the same images to be added to each controller, just give each controller a same instance of the repo objects and adding/removing images only needs doing once.